# event.target and event.currenttarget

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript

I admit I am a novice to javascript and lightning, so I am asking this question . In what specific scenarios can we use event.target and event.currenttarget in lightning.
can somebody explain with s specific example.?

Comment: Here is a nice explanation on MDN. `event.currenttarget` It always refers to the element to which the event handler has been attached, as opposed to `event.target` which identifies the element on which the event occurred. Here is a nice visual representation. http://joequery.me/code/event-target-vs-event-currenttarget-30-seconds/

Answer (score 1):

When you are not trying to access namespaced components, for example:

```
<div class="potato" id="potat" name="potato name" onclick="myFunction()">
 ...
</div>
```

> Because of their markup, you might expect to access DOM elements via
>   event.target or event.currentTarget. However, this type of access
>   breaks encapsulation because it provides access to another component’s
>   DOM elements, which are subject to change.

Basically, if you try on the bellow component:

```
<lightning:button name="myButton" onclick="{!c.doSomething}"/>
```

it won't work:

You will need to use code compliant with Locker Service. To retrieve the component that fired the event, use `event.getSource()`.

you can find plenty of samples and further explanations in the Developer Documentation.

- [Event Handling in Base Lightning Components](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/lightning_base_events.htm)
- [Which Button Was Pressed?](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_which_button_pressed.htm)